# Store date plus 45 days in second column

Tags: sql, sql-server

There are two columns in a table in which the 1st column is "last reset date" and the 2nd is "next reset date". When I enter a date in the "last reset date" column I want plus 45 days to the "next reset date" column of 1st column

e.g. if last reset date = "17th April 2019" then next reset date would be "27th May 2019".

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Use TRIGGER - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: can you please share your code or table schema, also share your code you have tried so far.

Comment: Or just insert it at the same time as the `Last Reset Date` - hardly needs the complexity of a trigger.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend a computed field.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.ResetDate
(
     PersonName NVARCHAR(30),
     LastResetDate DATE,
     NextResetDate AS DATEADD(DAY, 45, LastResetDate) 
)    

INSERT INTO ResetDate (PersonName, LastResetDate) 
VALUES ('Fred', '2019-04-17T00:00:00.000'),
       ('Mary', '2019-06-19T00:00:00.000')

SELECT * FROM dbo.ResetDate

-- PersonName   LastResetDate   NextResetDate
-- Fred         2019-04-17      2019-06-01
-- Mary         2019-06-19      2019-08-03
```

Note:  You specify that the dates must differ by 45 days, but your example, 17th April 2019 and 27th May 2019, differ by 40 days.

Comment: Did you find this helpful?

Answer (score 0):

You may try this..

```
 Insert into [Table Name] ( InsertDate, NextDate )
 Values ( yourdate, DateAdd(day, 45, yourdate ) )
```

This is just sample code.

Comment: `INSERT INTO` needs values in a `VALUES (.,...)` construct - the `SET` is from an `UPDATE` statement.....